# count the lines in rdd depended on the lines context, pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I try to understand currently, how RDD works. For example, I want to count the lines based on the context in some RDD object. I have some experince with DataFrames and my code for DF, which has for example columns `A`, `B` and probably some other columns, is looking like:

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("filepath")
df2 = df.groupBy(['A', 'B']).count()
```

The logical part of this code is clear for me - I do `groupBy` operation over column name in DF. In RDD I don't have some column name, just similar lines, which could be a tuple or a Row objects... How I can count similar tuples and add it as integer to the unique line? For example my first code is:

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("filepath") 
rddob = df.rdd.map(lambda line:(line.A, line.B))
```

I do the map operation and create a tuple of the values from the keys `A` and `B`. The unique line doesn't have any keys anymore (this is most important difference to the DataFrame, which has column name).
Now I can produce something like this, but it calculate just a total number of lines in RDD.

```
rddcalc = rddob.distinct().count()
```

What I want for my output, is just:

```
((a1, b1), 2)
((a2, b2), 3)
((a2, b3), 1)
...
```

**PS**

I have found my personal solution for this question. Here: rdd is initial rdd, rddlist is a list of all lines, rddmod is a final modified rdd and consequently the solution.

```
rddlist = rdd.map(lambda line:(line.A, line.B)).map(lambda line: (line, 1)).countByKey().items()
rddmod = sc.parallelize(rddlist)
```

Comment: In fact `groupBy` isn't recommended because it requires shuffling the partitions, hence moving many data among all nodes.

Comment: @Alberto Bonsanto, thank you for the interest in this topic. I don't think that groupBy is dangerous for DF and for RDD it doesn't exist.

Comment: Well you can find some reasons explained by *databricks* here [Prefer reduceByKey over groupByKey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

Comment: ok, thank you, interesting article

Comment: Hi @Guforu, I have read this message a couple of times but I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the number of time a specific combination of tuple appear in your RDD?

Comment: @PinoSan, yes, with the help of RDD object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for here is a `reduceByKey`. This will give you a count of how many times each distinct pair of `(a,b)` lines appears.
It would look like this:

```
rddob = df.rdd.map(lambda line: (line.A + line.B, 1))
counts_by_key = rddob.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
```

You will now have key, value pairs of the form:
`((a,b), count-of-times-pair-appears)`

Please note that this only works if A and B are strings. If they are lists, you have to create a "primary key" type of object to perform the reduce on. You can't perform a `reduceByKey` where the primary key is some complicated object.

Comment: thank you for your respond. Actually I already found the solution, but didn't public it here. You are almost right, I created the keys as unique combination of (A and B values, but used countByKey as a final function. Thank you very much anyway

Comment: You should publish your solution so that other people can use it.

Comment: @Katya Handler, I have to say that after some tests I have to confirm that solution with reduceByKey() is much more efficient than countByKey(). I don't need to create the list and use sc.parallelize(), it is much more better to create rdd direct. Thank you